# How do I change my parents' email?

Tags: battle.net

I was signing up for a Battle.net account and since I was underage they asked for my parents' email. I entered my father's email. The problem is he was making a Battle.net account the very next day the email does not seem to work. He assumes it was because his email is linked to my account. Is there a way to change the parent email linked to my account? I don't want to terminate the account because I'm using a guest pass for Diablo and I have activated everything.

Comment: Off the top of my head, try contacting Blizzard support.

Comment: Just create a new email address and forward everything to his main email. Big companies like Blizzard are very slow with things that they have no workflow for.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to [battle.net](http://www.battle.net) and login.
2. Click on Account at the top of the screen
3. On the left is account details with Account Name. Click edit.

You should see a message on this page:

> Use this form to enter a new e-mail address, which will also become the new username for this Battle.net account.

From here, follow the directions.